# PHP in_array $_REQUEST

Tags: php, in-array

Estoy comprobando el **tratamiento de una página web**. Dispongo de una serie de IDs válidos, existentes en una tabla, almacenados en la variable $misids; (Devuelve un array).

Quiero comprobar que el usuario no sea "malo" y quiera acceder a un id NO existente de la página.

**Método obtenerIDs:**

```
static public function obtenerIDsCabanas(){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT idcabana FROM cabanas";
        $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
        //Creamos un array para almacenar los IDs.
        $misids = array();
        //Recorremos el array y añadimos en él los ids mediante array_push.
        while($idcabana = $registro->fetch()){
            //Array asociativo: al array $misids le pasamos $idcabana.
            array_push($misids, $idcabana);
        }
        //Devuelve el array $misids (asociativo).
        return $misids;
    }
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<?php
    $misids = BD::obtenerIDsCabanas();
    if(in_array($_REQUEST["idcabana"], $misids)){
        echo "SI existe el ID.";
    }else{
        echo "No existe el ID.";
    }
?>
```

**Preguntas:**

1) ¿Por qué siempre me sale "No existe el ID"?

Comment: Intenta colocar cada pregunta en un post diferente. Te recomendaria que publicases la del error en otra publicacion. Asi la gente que busque eso, lo encontrara mas facilmente.

Comment: Cierto es. Lo haré. Edito... Posteriormente abro la pregunta de la URL.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene $misids? ¿Puedes añadir el contenido del mismo? print_r

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [idcabana] => 1 [0] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [idcabana] => 2 [0] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [idcabana] => 3 [0] => 3 ) ). Tiene los valores 1-2-3, cualquiera que no sea esos, debe dar un echo "no existe".

Comment: ¿y la url que le pasas?

Comment: En esta parte, al separar las preguntas, sólo me refiero al problema del in_array.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70213/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-gdp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cosa es que tienes los datos en un array multidimensional, por lo que no tienes que profundizar algo mas. Tambien deberias comprobarlos con la clave, ya que es lo que estas buscando si no me equivoco.

Prueba con la siguiente funcion.

```
$misids = array ( array ( 'idcabana' => 1, '0' => 1 ) ,array ( 'idcabana' => 2 ,'0' => 2 ), array ( 'idcabana' => 3, '0' => 3 ) );

if(in_multiarray(1, $misids,"idcabana")){
    echo "SI existe el ID.";
}else{
    echo "No existe el ID.";
}

function in_multiarray($elem, $array,$field)
{
    $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
    $bottom = 0;
    while($bottom <= $top)
    {
        if($array[$bottom][$field] == $elem)
            return true;
        else 
            if(is_array($array[$bottom][$field]))
                if(in_multiarray($elem, ($array[$bottom][$field])))
                    return true;

        $bottom++;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

Editada para tu código:

```
$misids = BD::obtenerIDsCabanas();

if(in_multiarray($_REQUEST["idcabana"], $misids,"idcabana")){
    echo "SI existe el ID.";
}else{
    echo "No existe el ID.";
}

function in_multiarray($elem, $array,$field)
{
    $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
    $bottom = 0;
    while($bottom <= $top)
    {
        if($array[$bottom][$field] == $elem)
            return true;
        else 
            if(is_array($array[$bottom][$field]))
                if(in_multiarray($elem, ($array[$bottom][$field])))
                    return true;

        $bottom++;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias GDP, no conocía dicha información pero no responde a mi pregunta. Hablo de cuando el usuario escriba algo en la URL, y detecte que "eso no existe" y se pueda escribir, a modo de prueba, un echo en la web para saber que tiene un error. Pregunta1 y Pregunta2.

Comment: @omaza1990 he editado para responder a tu pregunta actual.

Comment: A tu código: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function in_multiarray() in C:\xampp\htdocs\daw\pruebas.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main}

Comment: Pero has añadido la funcion multiarray tambien? la tienes seguida. Es decir, deberias copiar todo el código.